# dplyr, group by and mutate - wrong result size

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Here is my example:

```
col_1 <- c('a','a','a','b','b')
col_4 <- c('h','h','k','t','t')
col_2 <- c('2015-10-10','2016-10-10','2015-10-10','2016-10-10','2016-10-10')
col_3 <- c(1,2,3,445,56)
test_df <- data.frame(col_1,col_2, col_3, col_4)


df_result <- test_df %>% group_by(.dots = c('col_1', 'col_4')) %>% mutate(result_col = max(col_3))
```

It produces the following error message:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  wrong result size (2), expected 5 or 1
```

Could you help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: use unquoted column names in `group_by`

Comment: @user127649 I tried your suggestion, it did not work

Comment: Sorry, not enough detail. How's this: `group_by(col_1, col_4)`,  ie remove the `.dots = (c())`

Comment: Why? Do you still get the same error? Or is it that your result is not as expected?

Comment: @user127649 Appologies, your last suggestion worked! Thank you! What is the purpose of `.dots`

Comment: Glad you got it working. `dplyr` uses non-standard evaluation. `.dots` is to work round this - see `vignette("nse")`, for an explanation better than any I could give

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
df_result <- test_df %>% group_by(col_1, col_4) %>% mutate(result_col = max(col_3))
```

Answer (score 1):

If, for some reason, you want to pass quoted column names, you'll have to use `group_by_` instead of `group_by`. Note `_` at the end of the function.

You can use all the `dplyr` verbs in similar fashion.